# How does executing a file change the std input?

Tags: shell, shell-script, terminal

Imagine I have a script, which contains the goto command.

The goto command will search in the **std input** for a line like this `: jumpHere`.

But the std input is by default the terminal. It only makes sense if the file/script is the std input for the goto command. **So where/who/what is changing the std input?**

ps. I'm talking about old Thompson-Shell, Unix v6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `goto` was a separate utility, so not part of the Thompson shell per-se.

When you invoke the Thomson shell as:

```
sh the-script
```

`sh` opens `the-script` on `stdin` (fd 0) as if you had written

```
sh < the-script
```

instead.

The `goto` command will `seek` stdin back to the beginning (which obviously if stdin were a terminal and not a regular file wouldn't work) then look for the label in there and would leave the cursor in the file just after that. Then the shell would carry on from there.

If you wanted a command in your script to read from what stdin was originally, you'd use the `<-` special redirection operator:

```
cmd <-
```

---

Note that with that same `goto` command, your script would also work with `bash` if you invoke your Thomson shell script as:

```
bash < the-script
```

`ksh93` can emulate that `goto` with special *seeking* redirection operators. For instance this Thomson shell script:

```
echo Start
: start
ls -ld /proc/self/fd/0
sleep 1
goto start
echo End never reached
```

Could be written in `ksh93` like:

```
echo Start
: start
ls -ld /proc/self/fd/0
sleep 1
exec <#((0)) <#": start"
echo End never reached
```

Both would run (provided you have the V6 `goto` command) with `ksh93` when invoked as:

```
ksh93 < the-script
```

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand how/where the std input was changed to the-script. :( I think you tell more about how goto in general works, but not how this works with the filedescriptors.

Comment: Now I understand! :) Is there any way you could change the std input then in the script to terminal?

Comment: @Joey. That's what the `<-` operator was for.